# Can a dead tree root still draw water?

Tags: botany

Can a tree whose roots have died due to whatever reason, let's say due to ringing, still draw water up? I personally doubt so but I believe that since all forms of conducting water up a plant requires only passive actions, such as root pressure or capillary action, and that having a dead tree root will not result in leaves dying, hence transpiration can still take place. Is it hence derived that a tree is able to continue taking up water even if their roots died, or, does it depend on the woodiness of the tree?

Edit: I still got no answer

Comment: It can draw a littly bit of water up, but without leaves the evaporation rate is minimal. im guessing that an live oak drinks a cubic meter every day in the summer, and a dead oak will evaporate 1 liter or so, wood becomes just a sponge.

Comment: I mean like since its just the roots that died,  the leaves havent died yet so transpiration can still take place?

Comment: Root pressure and capillary action are only able to raise water against gravity about 8 feet. You need transpiration to pull the water molecules the rest of the distance up the tree to the canopy. Xylem is dead anyway, even in a perfectly healthy plant.

Comment: From observation, trees are going to die if their roots die.  (Although with some you can induce new root growth on cuttings.)  Far more likely is that the leaves & trunk will die (or be broken/cut off), and new shoots will sprout from the living roots.